# How to write the SQL query to select an ID if all 7 day week numbers exists

Tags: sql, select, group-by, having-clause

I have a table similar to the one in the attached picture.

The IDs in the ID-2 column have 1-7 day of week numbers in 'Day of week'column e.g ID-2 = 100.

However, sometimes there won't have all 7 day of week numbers. For example in ID-2= 500 has the Day of Week numbers 3,4 and 6 missing.

In my SQL query I want to select the distinct ID when only if it has all 1-7 day of week numbers.

I wonder if someone could guide me on this? In SQL what concept can be used for it, i.e. Case, partition, self join etc?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`. Assming that `day_of_week` is always between `1` and `7`:

```
select id_2
from mytable
group by id_2
having count(distinct day_of_week) = 7
```

If there are no duplicates `(id2, day_of_week)` tuples, then the `having` clause can be more efficiently phrased as:

```
having count(*) = 7
```